# Android real-time developer notifications

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscription

In what situation we will receive this kind of notifications events ?

SUBSCRIPTION_PAUSE and SUBSCRIPTION_RESTARTED

I followed Android Real-time developer notifications reference guide but it was not clear to me. Any one can give a example for above notification types.

Answer (score 1):

- **SUBSCRIPTION_PAUSED**: a user can decide to "pause" their subscription for a given amount of time. It means the user won't have an active subscription during this period... but at the end the auto-renew process will start again. The `SUBSCRIPTION_PAUSED` RTN is sent at the beginning of this pause period (so, as described [in this schema](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#pause), at the "Pause starts").
- **SUBSCRIPTION_RESTARTED**: [as explained here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#restore), "*A cancelled subscription remains visible in the Play Store app until its expiration date. A user can restore a cancelled subscription before it expires by clicking Resubscribe (previously Restore) in the Subscriptions section in the Google Play Store app.*". If the user resubscribes this way, you will receive a `SUBSCRIPTION_RESTARTED` RTN